# Retrieving the name of an item in a database for the use in treeview object?

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes, names

I have code to populate a treeview object with parent nodes. the problem is i am unsure of how to get the names to reflect how they are in the database (microsoft access database). i am using vb.net if that helps, here is the code i have so far

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim mypath = "I:\Casegoods\Database\Expertpetrolia.mdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" & mypath)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim maxrows As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sql1 = "SELECT Due_Date FROM Supply_Date;"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Using conn
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)
        conn.Open()

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read()
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add('text to name them goes here, what can i use?)
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox("No Things found")
        End If

        dr.Close()
    End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `dr.Item("NAME_OF_COLUMN")` it returns Object, so you may have to cast it depending on what it is

Comment: I seem to have answered my own question as soon as i posted this. by putting dr("Due_Date") in the brackets it reads the name from each row in the table but just for due date. i belevie this to be working correctly now